# The else part in the logic is not working and not updating file content

Tags: java, file, properties

The requirement is:
Invoice number will be sent from the XSLT. I have to read the invoice number and update the count.
Example: Invoice_no=101 , first should check the file if 101 is not present initialize counter to 1 else  increment the counter to 1.   The logic is as follow

```
public static void LookupInsert( int invoiceNumber)
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    File propertiesfile = new File("Sequence.properties");
    if(propertiesfile.length()==0)
    {
        try{
            propertiesfile.createNewFile();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int value=1;
        properties.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(1).toString());
        try {
            properties.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    //if there is no invoice number in properties file then get(invoiceNumber) will be null
    if(props.get(invoiceNumber)== null)
    {
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(1).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("inside else");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(props.get(invoiceNumber).toString());
        value++;
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(value).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
// main() is used for testing
public static void main(String[] a) {
    LookupInsert(101);
    LookupInsert(102);
    LookupInsert(103);
    LookupInsert(104);
    LookupInsert(105);
    LookupInsert(106);
    LookupInsert(107);
    LookupInsert(108);
    LookupInsert(101);
}
```

Here else part is not working. its not incrementing the value. Kindly help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your counter variable here,  'value' is your counter here ?

Comment: Do you want to increment the variable `value`?

If so, try inserting a break point where you declare the `value` variable and see what gets assigned to it before you attempt to increment it. You'll have to run your code in debug mode to see this.

Comment: do you need to read last property and increment with one like 101=1 , 102=2, 103=3 like ?

Comment: are you aware of the fact that you have two different int value-variables? one in the first if-statement and one inside else? if you want to use the same variable, you need to take the declaration "int" away from this line:  int value = Integer.parseInt(props.get(invoiceNumber).toString()); and perhaps declare the variable somewhere else

Comment: @vels4j nopes.. its like when 101-1, 102-1, 101-2,101-3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistakes are you are reading system.properties and `propertyFile.get` instead of `propertyFile.getProperty`. Check the fixed code.

```
public static void lookupInsert(int invoiceNumber) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    File propertiesfile = new File("d:/rw/dump/Sequence.properties");
    if (propertiesfile.length() == 0) {
        try {
            propertiesfile.createNewFile();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int value = 1;
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(1).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ;
    }
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
    System.out.println("props " + props.toString());

    //if there is no invoice number in properties file then get(invoiceNumber) will be null
    if (props.getProperty(String.valueOf(invoiceNumber)) == null) {
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(1).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("inside else");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(String.valueOf(invoiceNumber)).toString());
        value++;
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(), new Integer(value).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. but this is not a good approach. Think what happen if you are running this for a long period.

Answer (score 0):

PFB complete working code:

```
    public static void LookupInsert(int invoiceNumber) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    File propertiesfile = new File("Sequence.properties");
    if (propertiesfile.length() == 0) {
        try {
            propertiesfile.createNewFile();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int value = 1;
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(),
                new Integer(1).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesfile));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // if there is no invoice number in properties file then
    // get(invoiceNumber) will be null
    if (props.get(invoiceNumber + "") == null) {
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(),
                new Integer(1).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("inside else");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(props.get(invoiceNumber + "")
                .toString());
        value++;
        props.setProperty(new Integer(invoiceNumber).toString(),
                new Integer(value).toString());
        try {
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(propertiesfile), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```